# algorithm for finding a straight line to separate class

Tags: algorithm

I want create algorithm, which find a straight line which will separate the most objects from the class. The line must be parallel to the X or Y axis. Example:
[image]

Above example present two class: circles filled and unfilled. Red line is a solution to the problem. Has anyone the idea how to find such a simple?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to Stack Overflow. Check out [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/369375) for more info; but this could even be considered a Math question IMO.

Comment: What is the complexity you aiming for? O(#objects)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier

Comment: The description of your problem is not at all clear. What do you mean, "separate the most items?" What problem does the red line in your example solve? Are you saying that it provides the largest grouping of non-filled circles that doesn't include any filled circles?

Answer (score 1):

Scan the items by increasing X. During the scan, maintain two counters that tell you the number of filled and unfilled items on the left of the vertical through the current X (the counts on the right are the complements).

Then keep the position that achieves "the most objects from the class" (up to you to assign some meaning to this criterion).

Repeat on Y and keep the best of both results.